# SmartGWT and Vaadin rtl support

Tags: java, gwt, vaadin, smartgwt, right-to-left

Does Vaadin or SmartGWT support RTL in their provided widgets/themes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least Vaadin 6.4.7 and before does not fully support RTL languages. There are some hacks to make some components work properly, but general support is still lacking.

There is a ticket for RTL support, please comment or support that ticket so the developers see that people are interested in that. This helps speed up the feature implementation. Or if you can provide patches to make it work, it would be fantastic.

http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/3093

Can't say for sure about SmartGWT, but at least none of the release notes on http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/release_notes.html#2_2 say anything about RTL support.

On smartclient forums in the Q&A section an admin has stated 2nd Oct 2010 that RTL support is "considered beta quality and not fully supported". TO me it is not clear wether this is the free SmartGWT or the commercial version, though. http://forums.smartclient.com/showpost.php?p=52511&postcount=6

Comment: Stale information, SmartGWT has supported RTL for some time.  Search for RTL here: http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/docs/I18n.html

Answer (score 2):

I do not know about vaadin but according to [this link](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee-latest/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/docs/I18n.html) from latest smart gwt java documentations:

> ListGrid columns, horizontal layouts, scrolling directions, etc will reverse order automatically.
>   Because RTL in some cases requires additional media files, RTL is only supported for the Enterprise, EnterpriseBlue and Graphite skins.

Have a nice time.